# CSS Cut of bottom of characters with line-height?

Tags: html, css, web

I am trying to get a text character to touch the borer below it.

I have no margin and no padding, but there is a gap because the font characters themselves seem to have space below the characters.

I tried to reduce the line-height, but this cuts of the top of the characters. I would like to cut off the bottom of the characters instead. Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The space below baseline is called descent in the typographic world. Unfortunately you cannot adjust this using CSS.

What you can do is to place your string inside a div. In the CSS set the `height` you wish, and set `overflow:hidden;`

### [Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/EfajG/)

```
<div class="cutter">
    This a test string
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.cutter {
    display:block;
    font-size:24px;
    height:20px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

The result:

[image: text cut at a random height]

As Dai points out in the comment, you can also place and positioning the text in a parent container and then apply a negative bottom margin.

Comment: You could also position the text in a parent and use a negative bottom-margin.

Answer (score 0):

Please check with this code snippet this might help you!

```
div {
   display: -webkit-box;
   -webkit-line-clamp: 4;
   -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
   overflow: hidden;
   text-overflow: ellipsis; 
}
```

I referred this to https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/css/css+text+truncate+max+height